# Set background completely black except a circle where opacity is 0%?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a webpage, and my niche is an older generation. Our tests for ease of use among that age group showed that they were confused about menu-based site navigation; some of the testers weren't even aware of what a site menu was.

We found that showing them the menu got most of them over the learning curve on how to navigate the site, so our simplest solution (barring reorganizing the entire site) is to put an overlay onto the webpage for a user's first time visit.

My design concept is to put a 75% opacity background, but to have a circle around the menu button be at 0%, and then putting an image over top with a huge arrow and text saying "CLICK HERE TO NAVIGATE THROUGH OUR SITE" or something like that. And then a button to continue.

The issue I'm having is I don't know how to set background opacity to 0% in just one spot, and I don't know how to word that in a simple search to see if Google can find a solution.

Please let me know if there's a way to do this with CSS.

Comment: where is your code so far?

Comment: As an alternative suggestion, you might want to consider something like this: http://bootstraptour.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a pseudo with a hudge shadow to draw the background of its parent but see trough it and position it on top of the element/part to see.

```css
.seeme {float:right;margin:0 5em;}
.howto {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.howto:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  height:120px;
  width:120px;
  box-shadow:0 0 1em white, 0 0 0 1000vw rgba(50,75,125,0.95);
  right:5em;
  top:10px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:solid red;
}
.howto article {
  margin:auto;
  padding:0 250px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="seeme" src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=see_me" />

<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>  Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
  tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
    elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
</blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
<div class="howto">
  <article><h1>Howto</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant more blabla</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
    sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>
</article>
</div>
```

Else a png image inserted in your "howto navigate" message will do just fine :) Your howto can be html pages stored aside the site and be called from script and from user from  a link of your menu into a lighbox alike frame.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does no allow for a child element to affect the parent's background, so this is really going against it. The way I would do this is make your circle cutout as a rectangular PNG image with the 75%/0% alpha transparency. Then put that in a grid:

```
-----------------------------
|     |               |     |
-----------------------------
|     |  image here   |     |
-----------------------------
|     |               |     |
-----------------------------
```

Where the background of all the cells is 75% opacity, except for the center cell which uses your png image with the cutout as the background. You can adjust the grid columns and rows to always position the image over the menu and to fill the screen.

If you really, really insist on doing this with CSS, there may be some tricks you can abuse, but I've never tried it so your mileage may vary:

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/making-holes-in-background/#post-158199

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   background-color: black; //whatever color you need
   opacity: 0.75;
}
```

This will make the whole background have 75% opacity. The circle will need to be a separate object and you don't have to worry about its opacity.

There are no ways (not that I know off) to set different opacity to different pieces of the same object.

Did that answer the question?

^^ and Eloff is totally right about a png image. This would be the most obvious solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is create a mask. CSS masks do exist, [but have limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks). So if you're using a particular browser like Chrome, then you should be able to use this technique.

A more complete demonstration of CSS masks can be found here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Another option is SVG which are vector graphics that support punching holes in their objects with masks. You can either load an SVG with a large translucent black background and a hole masked in it, or you could build the background and mask elements on the fly using javascript. The former is simpler but more limited in terms of screen size and controlling the mask shape, while the latter is more complicated to implement but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

that may help you : [Query Plugins For Doing Guided Tours](http://ninodezign.com/25-free-jquery-plugins-for-doing-guided-tours-through-a-website/)